# access to license server

Tags: windows, networking, vpn, license-key

In my research group we use several programs which each require a license key. We have set up a license server that allows PCs within the research group's wired network to use the licenses available. However I am interested in using some of these prgrams from home.

Is it possible to use a VPN connection to connect to the license server or any other computers within the network in order to use the licenses available in the license server?

Does anyone have a suggestion to get it done and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to use a [VPN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network) to achieve this.

First start the VPN connection. The result is that your PC appears to be on the local network of your research group and it is now able to reach the license server. Next simple start the program which you want to use.

The only caveat is that you want to exit the the program **before** you end the VPN connection. If you do not do that, then you are likely to keep using licenses even after the program has shut down. (With no VPN it will no longer be able to tell the license servers that the license is no longer in use).